# Is there a way to put a debbuger everytime control comes to a script in network tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-console

I actually wanted to know if there is a way to stop the execution everytime control comes to one particular script file from another in chrome developer console, I know how to put breakpoints at a particular line,
But wanna how to stop execution when control comes to a file 
I am not sure if we can do this, but if there is please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No. You can break on XHR requests occurring if the script is pulled in dynamically. Other than that you can't tell the DevTools to break on a given file name being loaded.